# Convert Json Array to Qr code and Retrieve it to a json array Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a flutter app, where I am trying to save some data in shared preferences as a string array.

I would like to pass this array to qr code and generate a qr code.

And later when I recieve it generates the same array.

Is this Possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, You can do it in simple way like -

**First**, Create `JSONObject` from String Array,

```
var json = jsonEncode(list.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList());
```

**Second**, Generate QR code from above json string by using this flutter library-

[Fltter QR Code Generator](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_flutter)

**Last**, Get `stringValue` from scanning QR and convert it to `JSONOject`

And For scanning this generated QR, You can use any flutter library like-

[QR Scanner](https://github.com/mikebuss/MTBBarcodeScanner)

Comment: Could you also tell me how to Get stringValue from scanning QR and convert it to JSONOject

Comment: Look into the documentation of specified library above and implement the code for scanning. and Do Json-Parsing again from resulted string.

Comment: I have implemeted scanning. What I cant correctly do is parsing the string to convert it back to json

Comment: List<String> list = json.decode(receivedString); - to do json parsing

Comment: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<String>' thew this error

Comment: See this: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18979